# C++ Global Project Call Graph

Tags: c++, doxygen, graphviz, dot, call-graph

I want to extract a project-wise function call graph in C++ for static analysis purposes (no need for graphic visualization). I tried with **doxygen**, which uses **graphviz** to extract .dot files which are exported in visually in the documentation.

The problem here, is that the output consists in *many* .dot files, one per function, but I need to compute a **global .dot file** of the entire network instead.

I've searched for tools that can merge different .dot files in a single one, and I've found **gvpack**, but this tool seems to fail in associating functions defined in the different graphs (eg. if I have two functions `doOperation()` and `doAnotherOperation()` which both call `logOperation()`, the resulting .dot file contains two `logOperation()` nodes instead of one).

What tool can I use? My only requirement is the .dot compatibility, because I have one other module in python that imports a graph from a dot file (with the **networkx** library).

Comment: Did you have a look at the call graph of the "main" function whilst setting the configuration variable (in the Doxyfile) DOT_GRAPH_MAX_NODES to 0 and MAX_GRAPH_DEPTH to the maximum (might take some time).

Comment: Thanks, but what if I have more entry points (more main functions)? Also, I would like to give in input only the source folder, without specifying manually the location of the main function(s).

Comment: A complete graph is created for each function so this might work for you.